# Codec pen code issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I asked this question before but  I'm here to clarify it again:)
hello you all

I copied a code from code pen 
its working on code pen
but when I copied it ,it didn't work with me!
the html and css worked!
but the javascript part didn't
so I cant switch between tabs
I don't know whats the problem?
this is the code in code pen:
https://codepen.io/ehermanson/pen/KwKWEv?editors=1000
and this is my code:

```
 $(".form").find("input, textarea").on("keyup blur focus", function(e) {
    var $this = $(this), label = $this.prev("label");

  if (e.type === "keyup") {
    if ($this.val() === "") {
      label.removeClass("active highlight");
    } else {
      label.addClass("active highlight");
    }
  } else if (e.type === "blur") {
    if ($this.val() === "") {
      label.removeClass("active highlight");
    } else {
      label.removeClass("highlight");
    }
  } else if (e.type === "focus") {
    if ($this.val() === "") {
      label.removeClass("highlight");
    } else if ($this.val() !== "") {
      label.addClass("highlight");
    }
  }
});

$(".tab a").on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  $(this).parent().addClass("active");
  $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass("active");

  target = $(this).attr("href");

  $(".tab-content > div").not(target).hide();

  $(target).fadeIn(600);
});
```

and I put this code between () tags
is that correct?

Comment: First thing to do when debugging JS: check the console for errors. Also make sure you've included jQuery.js in the page properly, and are running your code in a document.ready event handler

Comment: I have put this code between< script > tags

Comment: how? @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: `//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js` is linked to that codepen.. do you have linked `jquery`?

Comment: In Chrome you can right click the page > Inspect, or press F12

Comment: Or `Ctrl + Shift + J` for console directly :)

Comment: @Strawberry This may also help you: http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan maybe a link to a `HTML + JS get started` would be better.

Comment: @Nitro.de that's what I did link to

Comment: @Strawberry The code in your question relies on an external library called *jQuery* - in the CodePen, if you go to Settings > JavaScript, you'll notice that the first textbox there is a link to the library. When you copy and paste the code, if you don't also include jQuery, your code will not work. Rory suggested a great link that goes into a bit more detail.

Comment: how do I link it ?@Nitro.de can you please tell me how?

Comment: @Strawberry That's a fundamental part of not just JavaScript, but HTML in general. Look up how to include external scripts on your HTML page - there are probably thousands of results on Google.

Comment: //cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js

Comment: how to add the above link to my html?

Comment: how to link //cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js to my html @Santi ?

Comment: Should I just copy and paste my previous comment...?

Comment: I'm sorry .. I know how to link css style sheets to my html .. but jquery no!

Comment: I just want the beginning should I use <link > tag or what? @Santi

Comment: Evidently. You can seriously type anything even remotely close into any search engine and find your answer in 2 seconds. [**jQuery - Get Started**](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp).